# Why do the navigation borders ignore my anchor tags when I reduce screen width?

Tags: html, css

I'm just building a mini test project in an online HTML/CSS course I'm doing for beginners and I don't understand why my navbar content doesn't respond to screen width. The header border goes right through my content if you keep reducing screen width (I've left borders on so you can see that happening).

I have copied my code and the course instructor's code below so that so you guys can tell me why his works but mine doesn't. The only major difference I see is that I used anchor tags whereas he used button tags for navigation but I still don't get why that is a problem (I set my anchor tags to display:block; in case their inline display was the issue).

My code:

```css
/*mycss.css*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  border: 1px solid hotpink;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 10vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border-right: 1px solid #D7DBDD;
}

div#top-nav {
  border: 5px solid green;
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ul {
  border: 1px solid gold;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  /* text-align: center; */
}

li a {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #16A2D7;
  font-size: font-size: 2vw;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #EEF3F5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css">-->
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div id="top-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="bg-gray">Inbox</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Accounts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Legal</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Instructor's code:

```css
/*main.css*/
html,
body,
div,
nav,
button {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  color: #16A2D7;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

#sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  /* arrange child elements */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* format */
  border-right: 1px solid #D7DBDD;
  width: fit-content;
  /*the width*/
}

.sidebar-child {
  /* arrange child elements */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sbc-top {
  /* format */
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.sbc-btm {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

button {
  /* format */
  color: inherit;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 10rem;
  /*the width*/
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #EEF3F5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sidebar Menu</title>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">-->
</head>

<body>

  <div id="sidebar">
    <nav class="sidebar-child sbc-top">
      <button>Inbox</button>
      <button>Contact</button>
      <button>Accounts</button>
    </nav>
    <div class="sidebar-child sbc-btm">
      <button>Legal</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First.. this needs fixed - `font-size: font-size: 2vw;` you have typed font-size twice. Second `vw` shouldn't be used for font sizings... instead use either `px` or `em`/`rem` or maybe `pt` for printing

Answer (score 0):

The chief thing that is causing you issues is this rule:

```
header {
  width: 10vw;
}
```

This means, no matter what, make my `<header>` have width equal to 10% of the width of the viewport.  This doesn't account for size of the content within.  Take a look at your professor's rule for the `#sidebar`, it uses [`width: fit-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#fit-content) which doesn't limit the size of the container.

An additional issue is that you are using:

```
li a {
  display: block;
}
```

Which means the `<a>` are going to try and eat as much space as they.  Normally, they are `inline` which causes them not to try to fill out width.  Depending on what presentation you are trying to make, you should remove the `width: 10vw;` and the `display: block;` to start.